# Nginx redirect non-www to www of domain with custom port

Tags: web, nginx, server

I have a domain with a custom port that would want to redirect from non-www to www. For example: from example.com:6789 to www.example.com:6789.

My current .conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server{
    listen       6789;
    server_name  example.com;
    return       301 http://www.example.com:6789$request_uri;
}
```

What should i do to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Use rewrite instead of return

Following config should work

```
server{
    listen       6789;
    server_name  example.com;
    rewrite ^/$ http://www.example.com:6789 permanent;
}
```

Comment: have tried and not working. does it work if it shares the same file with another setup for port 80?

Comment: [emerg] 1095#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:6789 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: [emerg] 1095#0: still could not bind()

Comment: Hi @sachin, the above are 2 new lines i noticed in error_log

Comment: `bind() to 0.0.0.0:6789 failed (98: Address already in use) `

It means port 6789 is alreday in use by other application or nginx itself